# How to Request Location Updates in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

> Hi, I am fetching users current location and complete Address in my app. I am getting Latitude and Longitude using this code :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     private void getCurrentLocation() {
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            //when success
            public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
    
                if (location != null) {
                    //sync map
                    Log.e("Getting Lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                    Log.e("Getting Long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                    String address = getCompleteAddressString(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    userLocation.setText(aa.trim());
    }
       }
```

> **Output** :

```
Getting Lat :26.1738506
Gettig Long :91.7741039
```

> This is the code for getting complete address from latitude and longitude:

```
  private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
    String strAdd = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

            for (int i = 0; i <= returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            Log.e("My loction address", strReturnedAddress.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
    }
    return strAdd;
}
```

> I am getting the complete address as well , but the Issue is this code executes only after I try for `10-15 times`.

> Also, please note, this code executes on `onCreateView` method and runs on the `mainThread` . What should I do , so that this i can get the current location everytime I launch the app

> **UPDATE** : I realised getLastLocation() might be null. So, what is the workaround here ? Pls help

Comment: Your problem is relying on `client.getLastLocation()`. There might not be a "last location" available. Android devices don't track their location all the time if no application requests location updates. So, to get a fresh up-to-date location you should request location updates.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen how to do it . Please guide

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates)